# R Speed up this code which calculates intermediate XY coordinates along a roadway link

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I have a function that calculates the XY coordinates along a roadway link at every 5-second interval. This code works fine. However, it takes about 3 minutes to get the result on a 1% sample. Please note that the 1% sample has about 1.95 million rows of data. Assuming a linear scale, the 100% sample could take about 5 hours. So, I am interested in speeding up this code to save the run time.

Below is the code.

```
routeptcalc <- function (pid, time1, time2, x1, y1, x2, y2, speed) {
  theta <- asin((y2-y1)/sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2))
  segtime <- 5
  i <- 1
  k <- vector("list")
  while (time1+5<time2)
  {
    len <- speed*segtime
    k[[i]] <- c(pid, x1+len*cos(theta), y1+len*sin(theta), time1+5)
    segtime <- segtime+5
    time1 <- time1+5 
    i <- i+1
  }    
  k
}

dt <- mapply(routeptcalc, x2$person, x2$time1, x2$time2, x2$STRTX, x2$STRTY, x2$ENDX, x2$ENDY, x2$trvlspeed)
dt <- matrix(unlist(dt), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Here is a small data sample.

```
> dput(head(x2))
structure(list(link1 = c(31047, 31117, 31176, 31293, 31278, 31394
), person = c(851, 851, 851, 851, 851, 851), time1 = c(53520, 
53819, 53884, 53983, 54009, 54078), type1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("arrival", "departure", "entered link", 
"left link"), class = "factor"), seqid1 = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11
), time2 = c(53819, 53884, 53983, 54009, 54078, 54133), link2 = c(31047, 
31117, 31176, 31293, 31278, 31394), type2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("arrival", "departure", "entered link", 
"left link"), class = "factor"), seqid2 = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12
), Length = c(847.067369691, 1216.60125775, 936.746699633, 381.795865634, 
1003.66563039, 798.590203996), STRTX = c(342942.660113, 343697.09589, 
344911.673823, 344848.208997, 344472.853848, 343946.808997), 
    STRTY = c(3114326.45681, 3114711.61883, 3114781.75488, 3115716.34923, 
    3115786.18185, 3116640.94586), ENDX = c(343697.09589, 344911.673823, 
    344848.208997, 344472.853848, 343946.808997, 343727.074166
    ), ENDY = c(3114711.61883, 3114781.75488, 3115716.34923, 
    3115786.18185, 3116640.94586, 3117408.71074), trvlspeed = c(2.83300123642475, 
    18.7169424269231, 9.46208787508081, 14.6844563705385, 14.5458787013043, 
    14.5198218908364)), .Names = c("link1", "person", "time1", 
"type1", "seqid1", "time2", "link2", "type2", "seqid2", "Length", 
"STRTX", "STRTY", "ENDX", "ENDY", "trvlspeed"), row.names = c(1894086L, 
1898954L, 1902861L, 1909903L, 1909303L, 1915772L), class = "data.frame")
```

A brief explanation of the data:

Each row in the data frame corresponds to an independent record that gives information on person id (person), when a person enters link (time1), when he exits it (time2), link length (Length), start and end UTM coordinates of the link (STRTX, STRTY, ENDX, ENDY), and the travel speed (trvlspeed) on the link. You need not worry about the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your the above routine is performing slowly is the while loop inside your function.  It looks like you are manually integrating the travel distance on each iteration of the loop.  Since the assumption is straight line travel from point A to point B at a constant velocity, the problem reduces down to simple arithmetic which can then be vectorized in R.

Try this:

```
routefast <- function (pid, time1, time2, x1, y1, x2, y2, speed) {
  segtime <- 5       #5 sec interals
  dt<-(time2-time1)  #total number of seconds
  seqs<-dt %/% segtime #integer number of 5 sec intervals
  deltax<-(x2-x1)
  deltay<-(y2-y1)
  xspeed<-deltax/dt  
  yspeed<-deltay/dt
  x<-xspeed*segtime*c(1:seqs)+x1
  y<-yspeed*segtime*c(1:seqs)+y1
  t<-segtime*c(1:seqs)+time1
  data.frame(pid,x,y,t)
}
```

The return of each from each function call is a data frame, if you like change the data.frame to cbind if you prefer to have a matrix returned.

The code could be simplified a bit but I left all of the variables in to relate back to the physics.  If necessary I can provide a better explanation of the code.

Comment: Should I still call this function using `dk <- mapply(routefast, x2$person, x2$time1, x2$time2, x2$STRTX, x2$STRTY, x2$ENDX, x2$ENDY, x2$trvlspeed)`? Your function works about 5.8 times faster than mine on a small sample with 7 rows of data. But, when I try it on the 1% sample (which has about 1.95 million rows) the code is still running even after 10 minutes. My function call gave the result in about 3 minutes. I do not know if my function call is the culprit here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, I made the correction.  I am confused about your results.  almost 6x faster on 7 rows yet on the larger sample over 3x slower...  I am wondering if the merge step post mapply is causing issues.  I am at a lost to explain the differences.

Comment: Ok. The code just finished running and took about 18 minutes in-total. Me too. It is puzzling that the function would slow down on a large sample.

Comment: I would trying used cbind instead of creating a data frame at the end of each call, then use do.call(rbind, dt), to bind all of the matrixes together.  Maybe that would be an improvement.

Comment: Ok. As you suggested, I used `cbind(pid,x,y,t)` instead of `data.frame(pid,x,y,t)`. Now your function performs 65x faster compared to my original one (for the 7 row sample). For the 1% sample, it took about 40 seconds. Obviously, this is much better compared to earlier results. But, this is not 65x faster compared to my code for the 1% sample, right? I do not know if speeds can be linearly scaled. Moreover, is there a way to apply the function only once as oppossed to repeatedly calling it using mapply?

Comment: Cool, I am glad the solution is working better.  I have seen discussions here  at stack overflow using matrix for improving performance.  I am not sure how one would vectorize the resulting arrays for x, y and t and then rearrange them into a final matrix.  With a final sample size of 20 million rows, will memory become a issue?  If so, writing smaller chucks of to disk might be a work around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111172/discussion-between-gandalf-and-dave2e).